# Password not less than 6 characters Validator using RegEx in ASP. Net

Tags: asp.net, validation

I need a Validator which makes sure that the Password is not less than 6 characters, I need the RegEx code for it. Thanks.

Comment: It's a bit overkill to use a RegEx for this ofcourse..

Comment: @MichielvanVaardegem : regex are short and cool ... no more if-else conditions, loops etc required

Comment: @AmitRanjan true, but for checking a length of a string, it is overkill

Comment: @MichielvanVaardegem: Case (i) If (Regex.IsMatch(expr))
or 
case (ii) If(paswd.Length<6) { // some mess} else { //proceed}. ALso sometime we need extra checks for null and empty too. But Incase of regex it will do all for you..

Comment: @AmitRanjan if(passwd == null || passwd.Length < 6){// error}   What is the problem? This is way faster then the RegEx

Comment: @MichielvanVaardegem What if put 10 or 12 blank spaces in the textbox. Then your said conditions will get satisfied. and fyi, blank spaces are not considered as a part of password.

Comment: @AmitRanjan A simple .Replace(" ", "").Length is still faster than the Regex

Comment: @MichielvanVaardegem : Ok, lets stop it here... You win I loose..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex  should be ^.{6,}$.